# Inputing multiple space seperated integers in one line (java)

Tags: java, input

recently i started learning java and i came across an annoying issue which i did not find an answer for. when recieving an input you can't define 2 diffrent variables in one line. (unless it's an array, and then it's inside a loop)
for exemple, here are 5 diffrent integers, and i wrote 5 diffrent lines to define them all:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int 1 = input.nextInt();
        int 2 = input.nextInt();
        int 3 = input.nextInt();
        int 4 = input.nextInt();
        int 5 = input.nextInt();
```

it is important to read all of them space seperated, and they can't be inputed together to a sring and then be seperated, or to an array.

is there a way to minimize those 5 lines to 1 and still read all these integers space seperated?
thanks to whoever answers!

Comment: variable names can't start with a number. apart from that: you'll have to either use an array, or read every integer separately

Comment: thanks to you both!
i dont want to use an array beacuae i need the integers to have names. (and i wrote numbers just for the exemple, i know i can't do it usually)

Comment: @singhakash the first element would be on index 0. :)

Comment: If you need named variables then you need 5 statements to read the integers and assign them to a named variable. Alternatively you could use an array and named indices like `int varX = numbers[indexX]; //read integers into numbers[]`

Comment: Maybe there's a problem understanding what you actually need/want. Can you provide some example of how you'd imagine it _should_ look like?

Comment: you actually helped a bit with your index naming solution. as for your question, i Imagined something like:
                                `1,2,3,4,5 = input.nextInt();`

Answer (score 2):

Well...

```
int i1 = input.nextInt(), 
    i2 = input.nextInt(),
    i3 = input.nextInt(),
    i4 = input.nextInt(),
    i5 = input.nextInt();
```

This is only 1 statement.

Comment: helpful, but unfortunately irelevant to the problem i am currently solving.